# angular $watch is triggered on init?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('TheCtrl', ['$scope', function (scope) {

    scope.user = {
        name: "木士羽",
        email: 'fdaf@qfdsafq.com',
    };

    scope.$watch('user.name', function () {
        console.log('change');
    });

}]);

angular.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['app']);
```

when page is loaded, 'change' is printed in console.

`$watch` is triggered when  init. How to avoid it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about this approach:

1st time `oldValue` will be equal to `newValue`, so avoid this by `if` validation.

```
$scope.$watch(
      function() {
        return $scope.user.name;
       },
       function(newValue, oldValue) {
           if (oldValue !== newValue) {
               // .....
            }
        });
```

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8xuuv1z/)</kbd>

BTW, its a good practice to write `if (oldValue !== newValue){ /* ...*/}` in watchers to avoid additional code execution under watch

Answer (score 0):

For the first time you can initialize a flag to true and once the watch is triggered it can be set to false. So that watch does not get triggered. 
    var firstTime = true
    and then when the first $watch fires, do

```
$scope.$watch('testValue', function() {
if (firstTime) {
$timeout(function() { firstTime = false; });
} else {
   //perform operation.
```

}

Second method which is recommended by the angular doc 
The first time watch listener is called, the old value and the new value  are identical. so check for not equal condition as given below

```
  $scope.$watch('testValue', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue !== oldValue) {
      // perform your operation 
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) you should be checking whether the new value and old value differ e.g.

```
$scope.$watch('user.name', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal !== oldVal) {
    // Do something with newVal
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
scope.$watch('user.name', function (val) {
    if (val !== undefined) {
        console.log('change');
    }
});
```

Comment: It would be ideal to add some description to the code. Just with this answer, nobody can tell what you've done, how it works or why it works that way.

Comment: i think everyone knows what ```val !== undefined``` means.